# Connecting to IBM MQ over SSL via .net client

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ibm-mq, mq

I am trying to connect to a MQ server queue via a .NET client. I need to use the certificate for secured communication. Here is the code that I have:

```
MQEnvironment.SSLKeyRepository = "*SYSTEM";
MQEnvironment.ConnectionName = connectionName;
MQEnvironment.Channel = channelName;
MQEnvironment.properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
MQEnvironment.SSLCipherSpec = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"; 

queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, channelName, connectionName);

queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(SendQueueName,MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
queueMessage = new MQMessage();
queueMessage.WriteString(message);
queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
queue.Put(queueMessage, new MQPutMessageOptions());
```

Every time I try to put the message on the queue, I get this error message

```
Reason Code: 2059
MQexp.Message: MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

I have checked my variables for the queue manager name, queue name etc and they are correct. 
I was also able to connect to a different queue without SSL, I believe that my code is not furnishing enough information to establish a successful connection.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Kunal

Comment: Can you show us what the queue manager error logs say? You can find the error logs under \ProgramData\IBM\MQ\<qmgr>\errors directory if you have done typical installation. Also are you using MQ v8?

Comment: Here is the server side error - AMQ9639: Remote channel '<MY_CHANNEL>' did not specify a CipherSpec.

Comment: You have specified CipherSpec in the client application. But have you configured your queue manager and channel to use SSL?

Comment: Have a look at this blog:https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/mq_v8_dot_net_samples_can_create_ssl_connection_in_managed_mode?maxresults=10&lang=en

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and error message. After enabling tracing I was able to isolate the problem. 
I always wondered, how the client is selecting the correct client certificate from the store. The trace output revealed following:

```
000001B2 15:53:46.828145   20776.10    Created an instance of SSLStreams
000001B3 15:53:46.828145   20776.10    Setting current certificate store as 'Computer'
000001B4 15:53:46.828145   20776.10    Created store object to access certificates
000001B5 15:53:46.834145   20776.10    Opened store
000001B6 15:53:46.834145   20776.10    Accessing certificate - ibmwebspheremqmyusername
000001B7 15:53:46.835145   20776.10    TLS12 supported - True
000001B8 15:53:46.837145   20776.10    Setting SslProtol as Tls
000001B9 15:53:46.837145   20776.10    Starting SSL Authentication
```

In my case, I had to set the **friendly name of the client certificate** to ibmwebspheremq**myusername** (replace "myusername" with your userid) and set the label in the code aswell:

```
properties.Add(MQC.MQCA_CERT_LABEL, "ibmwebspheremqmyusername");
```

To enable tracing, add following to your app.config/web.config where the path points to a location that contains a file named **mqtrace.config**:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MQTRACECONFIGFILEPATH" value="C:\MQTRACECONFIG" />
</appSettings>
```

Sample content of mqtrace.config (specified directories must exist in advance):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<traceSettings>
  <MQTRACELEVEL>2</MQTRACELEVEL>
  <MQTRACEPATH>C:\MQTRACEPATH</MQTRACEPATH>
  <MQERRORPATH>C:\MQERRORLOGPATH</MQERRORPATH>
</traceSettings>
```

Here are some links for more detail:

Tracing:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q123550_.htm
Why label:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21245474