# Connecting to MQ from C# application using .JKS file

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I am working on a C# application that needs to make connection to WMQ queue(remote server) that is SSL secured.
However it is failing with:

> MQQueueManager error occurred: 
>   msg: MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR

I am using MQ client version 7.1.0.9.
I doubt if I am passing the SSL configuration correctly. I am provided a .JKS keystore that I am converting to .KDB but that did not help.

Below are the properties I am using :

```
sslKeyRepository = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\SSL\key"
cipherSpec = SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, cipherSpec);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, sslKeyRepository);

MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, connectionProperties);
```

> "key" in the sslKeyRepository above is the name of the .KDB file I have generated from JKS.

How can I use the provided .JKS file with my C# code to access the MQ?

Comment: Are you using MQ in unmanaged mode (with full MQ client install) or in managed mode with just the amqmdnet.dll present?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code around how you are passing the the connection details and key store information.

Comment: Also JKS is Java Key Store and you can not use this directly from C# as far as I know, you would need to convert it to something else and the answer that would depend on the mode you use (unmanaged or managed mode).

Comment: @JoshMc- I have the full MQ client installed.
Yes, this is what I believe too that JKS cannot be used directly so I looked up a little and found out that I need to used CMS but I am not sure how to convert JKS to CMS.

Comment: Other people have posted C# MQ SSL questions - you should check the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663231/net-client-connecting-to-ibm-mq-over-ssl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898528/connecting-to-ibm-mq-over-ssl-via-net-client developerWorks C# MQ SSL blog posting: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/mq_v8_dot_net_samples_can_create_ssl_connection_in_managed_mode?lang=en Slideshare C# MQ SSL Sending/Receiving messages:
https://www.slideshare.net/ShreeshaRao3/ibm-mq-with-c-sending-and-receiving-messages

Comment: Can you confirm you are not specifying manged mode with something like setting the property `MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY` to `MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED`?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that Managed mode does not support TLS unto v8.  Also note that v7.1 has been out of support since April 30th 2017.  Please provide the code that shows how you are setting hostname, port, sslciph, channel, etc in order to help.  Read the help senter on the topic: [mcve]

Comment: The runmqckm command can be used to take a JKS as input and output a KDB file.  Can you give an example of what you specify for the value of `sslKeyRepository` in your example.

Comment: I have updated the connection properties I am using.
And also, Yes, I have set MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY to MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED. Earlier I had set it to
TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT. 
I changed it because using MQSERIES.MANAGED  I am able to make a connection to the MQ server as I confirmed it with the MQ team that they are seeing the connection requests.

Comment: MQ team said they are seeing below exception when I make a connection request using MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED:
Remote channel  did not specify a CipherSpec when the local
channel expected one to be specified

Comment: See above, managed mode client did not support TLS until v8.  7.1 and 7.5 do not support it.  With that being said, even with v8/v9 it is not as configurable as unmanaged mode, you can not specify a specific cipherspec without modifying the windows policy which is a machine wide setting for any program that uses SSLStream.

Comment: Likely it gets further and "connects" because it is ignoring the cipher/keystore settings and with unmanaged it fails because of an error with one of those settings.  Can you please provide what those two variables are set to (sanitize if you need to but make them look as similar to what you are actually specifying as possible.

Comment: @JoshMc - I have updated my question with the sslkeyrepository being used.

Comment: Does anything show up in your local file called `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\AMQERR01.LOG`?  It looks like your problem is that you are specifying the CipherSpec as `SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA` which is a IBM JRE CipherSuite  name.  You would want to specify exactly what the MQ admin has put on the `SVRCONN` channel, it could  be either `DES_SHA_EXPORT` or `TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA`, however unless the queue manager and the client set some setting to allow weak ciphers both are disabled in 7.1.0.7 and higher.  APAR IV73396 and IV73287.